# Mel-frequency function: error with matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, audio-processing, mfcc

I'm trying to make a prototype audio recognition system by following this link: http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~minhdo/teaching/speaker_recognition/. It is quite straightforward so there is almost nothing to worry about. But my problem is with the mel-frequency function. Here is the code as provided on the website:

```
function m = melfb(p, n, fs)
% MELFB         Determine matrix for a mel-spaced filterbank
%
% Inputs:       p   number of filters in filterbank
%               n   length of fft
%               fs  sample rate in Hz
%
% Outputs:      x   a (sparse) matrix containing the filterbank amplitudes
%                   size(x) = [p, 1+floor(n/2)]
%
% Usage:        For example, to compute the mel-scale spectrum of a
%               colum-vector signal s, with length n and sample rate fs:
%
%               f = fft(s);
%               m = melfb(p, n, fs);
%               n2 = 1 + floor(n/2);
%               z = m * abs(f(1:n2)).^2;
%
%               z would contain p samples of the desired mel-scale spectrum
%
%               To plot filterbanks e.g.:
%
%               plot(linspace(0, (12500/2), 129), melfb(20, 256, 12500)'),
%               title('Mel-spaced filterbank'), xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');

f0 = 700 / fs;
fn2 = floor(n/2);

lr = log(1 + 0.5/f0) / (p+1);

% convert to fft bin numbers with 0 for DC term
bl = n * (f0 * (exp([0 1 p p+1] * lr) - 1));

b1 = floor(bl(1)) + 1;
b2 = ceil(bl(2));
b3 = floor(bl(3));
b4 = min(fn2, ceil(bl(4))) - 1;

pf = log(1 + (b1:b4)/n/f0) / lr;
fp = floor(pf);
pm = pf - fp;

r = [fp(b2:b4) 1+fp(1:b3)];
c = [b2:b4 1:b3] + 1;
v = 2 * [1-pm(b2:b4) pm(1:b3)];

m = sparse(r, c, v, p, 1+fn2);
```

But it gave me an error:

> Error using  *  Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in MFFC (line 17) z = m * abs(f(1:n2)).^2;

When I include these 2 lines just before line 17:

```
size(m)
size(abs(f(1:n2)).^2)
```

It gave me :

```
ans =

    20    65


ans =

     1    65
```

So should I transpose the second matrix? Or should I interpret this as an row-wise multiplication and modify the code?

**Edit**: Here is the main function (I simply run MFCC()):

```
function result = MFFC()
[y Fs] = audioread('s1.wav');
% sound(y,Fs)

Frames = Frame_Blocking(y,128);
Windowed = Windowing(Frames);
spectrum = FFT_After_Windowing(Windowed);
%imagesc(mag2db(abs(spectrum)))

p = 20;
S = size(spectrum);
n = S(2);

f = spectrum;
m = melfb(p, n, Fs);
n2 = 1 + floor(n/2);
size(m)
size(abs(f(1:n2)).^2)
z = m * abs(f(1:n2)).^2;

result = z;
```

And here are the auxiliary functions:

```
function f = Frame_Blocking(y,N)
% Parameters: M = 100, N = 256
% Default : M = 100; N = 256;
M = fix(N/3);

Frames = [];
first = 1; last = N;
len = length(y);
while last <= len
    Frames = [Frames; y(first:last)'];
    first = first + M;
    last  = last + M;
end;
if last < len
    first = first + M;
    Frames = [Frames; y(first : len)];
end
f = Frames;

function f = Windowing(Frames)
S = size(Frames);
N = S(2);
M = S(1);
Windowed = zeros(M,N);
nn = 1:N;
wn = 0.54 - 0.46*cos(2*pi/(N-1)*(nn-1));
for ii = 1:M
    Windowed(ii,:) = Frames(ii,:).*wn;
end;
f = Windowed;

function f = FFT_After_Windowing(Windowed)
spectrum = fft(Windowed);
f = spectrum;
```

Comment: Please add how you called the function.

Comment: @Jørgen I have done as you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose `s` or transpose the resulting `f` (it's just a matter of convention).

There is nothing wrong with the `melfb` function you are using, merely with the dimensions of the signal in the example you are trying to run (in the commented lines 14-17).

```
%  f = fft(s);
%  m = melfb(p, n, fs);
%  n2 = 1 + floor(n/2);
%  z = m * abs(f(1:n2)).^2;
```

The example assumes that you are using a *"colum-vector signal s"*. From the size of your Fourier transformed `f` (done via `fft` which respects the input signal dimensions) your input signal `s` is a *row-vector signal*.

The part that gives you the error is the actual filtering operation that requires multiplying a `p x n2` matrix with a `n2 x 1` column-vector (i.e., each filter's response is multiplied pointwise with the Fourier of the input signal). Since your input `s` is `1 x n`, your `f` will be `1 x n` and the final matrix to vector multiplication for `z` will give an error.

Comment: Thank you, I found my errors (shame on me for this silly one). But I still want to know how to do it using only the matrix , i.e. without iterating through each column.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to gevang's anwer, I was able to find out my mistake. Here is how I modified the code:

```
function result = MFFC()
[y Fs] = audioread('s2.wav');
% sound(y,Fs)

Frames = Frame_Blocking(y,128);
Windowed = Windowing(Frames);
%spectrum = FFT_After_Windowing(Windowed');
%imagesc(mag2db(abs(spectrum)))

p = 20;
%S = size(spectrum);
%n = S(2);

%f = spectrum;

S1 = size(Windowed);

n  = S1(2);
n2 = 1 + floor(n/2);
%z  = zeros(S1(1),n2);
z = zeros(20,S1(1));
for ii=1: S1(1)

    s = (FFT_After_Windowing(Windowed(ii,:)'));

    f = fft(s);
    m = melfb(p,n,Fs);
    % n2 = 1 + floor(n/2);
    z(:,ii) = m * abs(f(1:n2)).^2;
end;


%f = FFT_After_Windowing(Windowed');
%S = size(f);
%n = S(2);
%size(f)
%m = melfb(p, n, Fs);
%n2 = 1 + floor(n/2);
%size(m)
%size(abs(f(1:n2)).^2)
%z = m * abs(f(1:n2)).^2;

result = z;
```

As you can see, I naively assumed that the function deals with row-wise matrices, but in fact it deals with column vectors (and maybe column-wise matrices). So I iterate through each column of the input matrix and then combine the results. 
But I don't think this is efficient and vectorized code. Also I still can't figure out how to do column-wise operations on the input matrix (Windowed - after the windowing step), instead of using a loop.